# Auto startup services on boot_completed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I was suffering to develop an startup app while phone startup, I got some codes from a web but still not yet succeed. This codes seemed to work in emulator, Bluestacks and in android version 5.1 but not working in android version 5.0.2.
I don`t know what is my wrong please anyone help me. 
Here is my code. Manifest
//
//

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.darcity.justshop"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/darcity_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/darcity_logo1"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <service
            android:name=".index.notify.ChatService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />

        <receiver
            android:name=".index.notify.BroadcastReceiverNew"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".index.Index"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_index" />
        <activity
            android:name=".index.category.FirstCategory"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_first_category" />
        <activity
            android:name=".index.details.Details"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_details" />
        <activity
            android:name=".index.full.Full"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_full" />
        <activity
            android:name=".messages.chating.Messages"
            android:label="" />
        <activity
            android:name=".messages.setting.MessageSetting"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_message_setting" />
        <activity
            android:name=".messages.users.Users"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_users" />
        <activity
            android:name=".messages.customers.Customers"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_customers" />
        <activity
            android:name=".messages.MessageBody"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_message_body" />
        <activity
            android:name=".index.search.Search"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Website"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_website" />
        <activity
            android:name=".crop.CropActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_crop" />
        <activity
            android:name=".crop.lib.CropImageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_crop" />


    </application>

</manifest>








    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import net.darcity.justshop.net.utils.Module;
    public class BroadcastReceiverNew extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public BroadcastReceiverNew() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Boot completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On which device have you tested? Code seems to be alright. For multiple actions you can use this, to specify individual action

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if(action != null) {
        if(action.equals("action1") {
            // CODE
        } else if (action.equals("action2") {
            // CODE
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was tested TECHNO C8

Comment: Thank for your answer but the problems is does not received from reboot. i add alert (Toast) but not display.

Comment: i want to get alert before to process an action. this is to ensue boot is working

Comment: I have tested your code on Samsung SM - T311 Android 4.2.2, API 17 and its working fine. I suggest you to test again.

Comment: Ok, Thanks let met test it again

Comment: Still does not working. my gradle (Module) is API 22 so does not issue?

Comment: using same device? TECHNO C8